# How to disable all code folding in Pycharm/Intellij Diff and Merge

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, folding

We can see the folding in this `Diff/Merge` screen by the `+` signs:

[image]

That used to not happen and I want to permanently disable the folding. How can I do that? JetBrains docs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/differences-viewer.html#diff-merge-viewer say the `Settings | Diff & Merge` can be used:

[image]

So here is that settings section:

[image]

So where is the setting to disable folding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `Expand All` - when invoked via context menu (right click) does the job. Just invoking via the keyboard shortcut `Shift-Cmd-+` curiously did *not* work

[image]

Comment: please feel free to submit a support ticket in order to figure out why the Keyboard shortcut doesn't work https://www.jetbrains.com/support/

Comment: Thanks Ruslan - I have a number of much higher priority keyboard issues logged - especially Option-foo combinations that used to work but no longer do.  I'd rather  leave more attention to them